# failed to update apt-get

Tags: 12.10, apt, updates

every time i run sudo apt-get update the following error occurs .

```
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ackondro/tibesti/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ackondro/tibesti/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ackondro/tibesti/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-split-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-split-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-split-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

this dose not bother me that much , but i would be very happy if i could get it fixed.

Thanks!

Comment: i don't have stormcloud and don't know what tibesti is